# Android Service that constantly updates Activity

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have built an app for running. It runs an `Activity` with a timer shown in the user interface, a gps listener that collects coordinates and a lot of other things (the activity does a lot of work).

Now the request of my client is to move all the activity logic in a `Service`. In this way, when you start a running session, the Service would start and the notification (very simple, just with a static text) would appear. The activity should keep track of the work made in the Service (timer should go on, speed should be shown, ecc...). Tapping on the notification should bring up the activity. If the activity is closed or crashes the Service should keep going on and when you tap on the notification a new Activity should be brought up without the user noticing any difference (the timer should keep showing the right time, the average speed should comprehend the speeds relevated before the activity crash, ecc...).

I know there are a lot of ways to do that.
What I am asking is: what is the best way? Are there examples of such behavior from where to start? What are the common errors I should avoid? Are there best practices to follow?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I developed an app with similar service behaviour. It also requires a service which collects data and some activities for showing the data.

For these kind of applications you want to keep the service alive until the user stopps it manualy but it is still possible for android that it kills the service if the device is low on memory.

For the service - activity interaction you need to bind to a service. A good documentation is available here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Be sure to return `START_STICKY` in the `onStartCommand` function of the service. This will make sure the intent will be null when the service was restored by the system and tell android that you start and stop your service explicit.

When binding to the service from the activity you need to check if the service is ready (was not restored by the system). This can be done by adding a "ready" field inside the service that is false by default and is set to true if the `onStartCommand` `intent` is not null. Therefore you can react properly to a restored service and start the app from the beginning.

To keep the service alive with a high priority you need to call `startForeground` inside the service. This also requires to show a notification so the users knows a service is running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Inside service you can use local broadcastmanager.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    } 
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo(); //do watever you want to push
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };
```